# Web browser does not show web pages properly in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have been struggling with displaying web content in web browser control on a Windows Phone 8 application.

The actual problem is web browser control not showing my web page (HTML file) at the correct size.

Here are the images that show my problem:

Web page shown in Windows Phone 8 web browser control:

[image: Web page shown in Windows Phone 8 web browser control]

Other devices like Android mobiles, iPhone and iPod & other devices show my web page  properly like this:

[image: normally my web page shown in other browsers]

my HTML Like this.,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Highest Runs 2013</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/orange.css">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#A31947">
         <div class="contenedor">
         <table align="center">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="10" class="lista_view">Highest  Runs 2014</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="lista_view">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="lista_view">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="lista_view"><strong>
              <bold>Player Name</bold>
            </strong></th>
            <th class="lista_view">Runs*</th>
            <th class="lista_view">M</th>
            <th class="lista_view">HS</th>
            <th class="lista_view">100</th>
            <th class="lista_view">50</th>
            <th class="lista_view">4s</th>
            <th class="lista_view">6s</th>
          </tr>
                  <tr><td colspan="10" class="lista_view">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </html>
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem? I don't know why WP8 web browser shows my web page like this.

I have checked in all devices browsers & desktop browsers and Windows Phone web browser is the only one with this problem.

Note:

I have tested my app with a Nokia Lumia 720 device and I am developing applications with  Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

¿Can you show your viewport meta tag? Try adding this to it

```
target-densitydpi=device-dpi
```

Each phone hace their own screen resolution and pixel density so you need to play with your viewport meta to make it looks good.

I can't say more without see your html code.

Comment: thanks for your reply daniel. just now i have added my HTML code., please see that and try to mark where i went wrong.,

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer from stack overflow itself., the problem was with my html., i have added view port meta tag in my HTML and ts works fine., like this.,

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```